# set background color to label swift

Tags: swift, colors, uikit

i hava a problem, i am tryinf to set background color to label, but it is not working

This is how i set label

```
private var imageLbel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .white
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 25)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.backgroundColor = GradientColor.setGradient()
        label.numberOfLines = 1
        return label
    }()
```

This is class for gradient

```
class GradientColor {

    static func setGradient(uiView: UIView) -> UIColor {

        let colorTop =  UIColor.orange
        let colorBottom = UIColor.systemOrange
        

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.frame = uiView.bounds

        uiView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
        
        return gradientLayer
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean? Your code looks completely invalid to me, i.e. I would expect that it would not even compile; both `imageLbel` and `setGradient` appear to be full of basic Swift language mistakes. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `backgroundColor` property accepts a value of type `UIColor` to be assigned, but your implementation of the function `setGradient(uiView:)` is not returning a value with the correct type. Also, you are calling `setGradient()` without passing the `uiView` argument required. I don't think your code even compiles correctly.

The function `setGradient(uiView:)` appears to be creating a `CAGradientLayer` instance and inserting it as a sublayer of the input `uiView`. I do not think returning a `UIColor` is required.

I suggest removing the line `label.backgroundColor = GradientColor.setGradient()`. Then, remove `-> UIColor` from the signature of `setGradient(uiView:)` so that it doesn't return anything, and remove `return gradientLayer`.

After that, somewhere after the label is added to the view hierarchy, call `setGradient(uiView:)` passing it `imageLbel`. Maybe in `viewDidLoad()` like this:

```swift
override viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    GradientColor.setGradient(uiView: imageLbel)
}
```